# Is there any statistical method testing the paired poisson data?

Tags: statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Is there a statistical method which was used for testing the paired Poisson data? Just like the paired $t$-test for numerical data and paired(McNemar)-$\chi^2$ for binomial distributed data, I'm looking for a test for paired Poisson distributed data.

Comment: I don't remember any specific test. Just to be clear: are we talking of the case in which a random sample $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)$ is available and we know about random vectors $(X_i,Y_i)$ that the marginal distributions for $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are $\mathcal P (\lambda_X)$ and $\mathcal P (\lambda_Y)$ so you want to test $H_0 \colon \lambda_X=\lambda_Y$?

Comment: Do we have any hypothesis about the joint distribution (I'm not saying it is strictly necessary, but I don't quite see how would it be)? (Of course, it has no sense to assume independence.)

Comment: I would give an example about this question, correct me if you find any thing wrong. I want to test the bacteria changes in lakes between day and night. I monitor the number of bacteria 8 a.m. and 8 p.m. for one hour, and I have 10 individual lakes. Obviously, the 10 lakes are independent, but the data from day and night will correlated to each other somehow. So I wonder if there is any statistical test method to test the difference (or the changes between day and night). I think this example is a little bit like the paired t-test.

Comment: Can you give an idea how big the Poisson counts of bacteria are? Less than 10? Dozens? Hundreds? Which is bigger AM or PM? One or two-sided test? Any negative differences? Can you show data for a few of the lakes? How large a difference in population  means btw AM and PM would be of practical importance? // I have several ideas, but need some help  deciding which one(s) to show.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not responded with information about your data, I will briefly
discuss a couple of possible tests using some fake data. (These are not the only possible tests, but should be appropriate for counts as large as those in the data shown.)
Consider the following data for AM, PM, and ten paired differences $d_i:$

```
       am pm   d
 [1,]  86 99 -13
 [2,]  96 90   6
 [3,] 108 77  31
 [4,]  95 97  -2
 [5,] 103 87  16
 [6,]  98 90   8
 [7,] 113 89  24
 [8,] 115 91  24
 [9,]  96 84  12
[10,]  96 90   6
```

Suppose we expect AM measurements to be larger than PM measurements, if there
is any difference. Thus we test $H_0: \lambda_a = \lambda_p$ against
the one-sided alternative $H_a: \lambda_a > \lambda_b.$

Because data are Poisson with fairly large means, it is reasonable to
assume that they are nearly normal. If the null hypothesis is true, it is
reasonable to assume that the usual statistic $T = \frac{\bar d - 0}{s_d/\sqrt{10}} = 2.6836$ for a paired t test is approximately distributed according to Student's t
distribution with $n - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9$ degrees of freedom. The critical
value for a test at the 5% significance level is $c = 2.262,$ so we
reject at the 5% level (the P-value is about 0.013).

Of course, the data are Poisson, not normal. So the critical value and the P-value may not be exactly correct. However, according to a Shapiro-Wilk test,
the data are consistent with normality. Also, the nonparametric (rank-based)
Wilcoxon signed-rank test rejects the null hypothesis that the *median* of the
$d_i$'s is zero (against the right-sided alternative) with P-value approximately 0.02; an exact P-value is not available because there happen to be ties among the $d_i.$
(The Wilcoxon test does not assume normality, but does assume that the $d_i$ are roughly symetical.)

*Note:* My fake data do not show significant correlation between AM and PM, and correlation would be typical with real paired data. But if anything, correlated data
with counts about the same size would tend to have even lower P-values in both the t and Wilcoxon tests. If you have questions about whether these tests
are appropriate for your data, please include some details along the lines
suggested in my earlier Comment, and I will take a look.

Comment: If nothing better is available, I would totally go for Wilcoxon. On the other hand, I have some concerns regarding the use of $t$ test which I haven't still studied as deeply as the situation would require. Among other things:
- If $\lambda$ is large enough it is clear that both $X$ and $Y$ (let these be the names of each sampled variable) will approach normal distributions. But will the differences $X-Y$ be approximately normal too?  How does correlation affect this distribution?
...

Comment: ...
- Even if distribution of $D_i$ is "approximately normal" (whatever this means), does $\sqrt{n}\tfrac{\bar{D}-\mu_D}{S_D}$ have an "approximately $t_{n-1}$" distribution? (Does $nS^2_D/\sigma^2_D$ even have an "approx. $\chi^2_{n-1}$" distribution?) Does the conclusion depend on the size of $n$?
- Even provided all that is true: how large is a large $\lambda$?
- And how powerful is the test for different combinations of $\lambda_X$, $\lambda_Y$ and $\rho_{XY}$?

Comment: Capsule replies: (1) In this case, if $X$ and $Y$ are normal, then $X-Y$ is normal, even if $X$ and $Y$ are correlated. (2) If $D_i$ are aprx normal then then $\frac{\bar D - \mu_d}{S_D/\sqrt{n}}$ is aprx T(n-1). (3) "Large' $\lambda$ is negotiable, roughly whatever makes (2) true. I chose Poissons with means > 75, which worked out nicely. (4) Power can be approximated by simulation, larger if $\rho$ is much greater than 0. // If OP wants a test that will work for his particular data instead of answers to quibbles, he can _show data_ and I will try to find one I can confidently verify is OK.

Comment: "If nothing better is available," I think the obvious choice would be a permutation test probably using pooled-t statistic as 'metric'. (Probably 
 also using simulated permutation dist'n, unless data are tractable with combinatorics). I tried this for several sets of fake Poisson  data and permutation dist'n is remarkably close to T(n-1). Clearly better power than Wilcoxon because info is not lost reducing data to ranks. (Checked that too.) // If you have a better suggestion, I would be happy to have it.